# making angularjs bootstrap multi select work

Tags: angularjs

i just happened to stumble upon this amazing multi-select textbox provided on the following link:
http://angularscript.com/bootstrap-multiple-select-angularjs/

i downloaded the zip and tried to run it on my local server.

the links were missing so i linked it to bootstrap and angular.js. But i was unsuccessful.can anyone try it out and see whats missing.

src/multiselect.html:

```
        <html>

        <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.2/angular-animate.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
            <script src="./multiselect.js"></script>
            <script src="./dist/angular-bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
            <script src="./dist/angular-bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>
            <script src="./dist/angular-bootstrap-multiselect-templates.js"></script>
        </head>


        <body>
        <div class="btn-group" style="width: 100%">
            <button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-default btn-block dropdown-toggle" ng-click="toggleDropdown()" ng-disabled="disabled">
                {{getButtonText()}}&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form"
                ng-style="{display: open ? 'block' : 'none'}" style="width: 100%; overflow-x: auto">

                <li ng-show="showSelectAll">
                    <a ng-click="selectAll()" href="">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Select All
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li ng-show="showUnselectAll">
                    <a ng-click="unselectAll()" href="">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Unselect All
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li ng-show="(showSelectAll || showUnselectAll)"
                    class="divider">
                </li>

                <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="option in selectedOptions" class="active">
                    <a class="item-selected" href="" ng-click="toggleItem(option); $event.stopPropagation()">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                        {{getDisplay(option)}}
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li ng-show="selectedOptions.length > 0" class="divider"></li>

                <li ng-show="showSearch">
                    <div class="dropdown-header">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="width: 100%;"
                               ng-model="searchFilter" placeholder="Search..." ng-change="updateOptions()"/>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li ng-show="showSearch" class="divider"></li>
                <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="option in unselectedOptions | filter:search() | limitTo: searchLimit"
                    ng-if="!isSelected(option)"
                    ng-class="{disabled : selectionLimit && selectedOptions.length >= selectionLimit}">
                    <a class="item-unselected" href="" ng-click="toggleItem(option); $event.stopPropagation()">
                        {{getDisplay(option)}}
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="divider" ng-show="selectionLimit > 1"></li>
                <li role="presentation" ng-show="selectionLimit > 1">
                    <a>{{selectedOptions.length || 0}} / {{selectionLimit}} selected</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

src/multiselect.js:

```
        (function () {
            'use strict';

            var multiselect = angular.module('btorfs.multiselect', ['btorfs.multiselect.templates']);

            multiselect.getRecursiveProperty = function (object, path) {
                return path.split('.').reduce(function (object, x) {
                    if (object) {
                        return object[x];
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }, object)
            };

            multiselect.directive('multiselect', function ($filter, $document, $log) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'AE',
                    scope: {
                        options: '=',
                        displayProp: '@',
                        idProp: '@',
                        searchLimit: '=?',
                        selectionLimit: '=?',
                        showSelectAll: '=?',
                        showUnselectAll: '=?',
                        showSearch: '=?',
                        searchFilter: '=?',
                        disabled: '=?ngDisabled',
                        defaultText: '@'
                    },
                    require: 'ngModel',
                    templateUrl: 'multiselect.html',
                    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $ngModelCtrl) {
                        $scope.selectionLimit = $scope.selectionLimit || 0;
                        $scope.searchLimit = $scope.searchLimit || 25;
                        $scope.defaultText = $scope.defaultText || 'Select';

                        $scope.searchFilter = '';

                        $scope.resolvedOptions = [];
                        if (typeof $scope.options !== 'function') {
                            $scope.resolvedOptions = $scope.options;
                        }

                        if (typeof $attrs.disabled != 'undefined') {
                            $scope.disabled = true;
                        }

                        $scope.toggleDropdown = function () {
                            $scope.open = !$scope.open;
                        };

                        var closeHandler = function (event) {
                            if (!$element[0].contains(event.target)) {
                                $scope.$apply(function () {
                                    $scope.open = false;
                                });
                            }
                        };

                        $document.on('click', closeHandler);

                        var updateSelectionLists = function () {
                            if (!$ngModelCtrl.$viewValue) {
                                if ($scope.selectedOptions) {
                                    $scope.selectedOptions = [];
                                }
                                $scope.unselectedOptions = $scope.resolvedOptions.slice(); // Take a copy
                            } else {
                                $scope.selectedOptions = $scope.resolvedOptions.filter(function (el) {
                                    var id = $scope.getId(el);
                                    for (var i = 0; i < $ngModelCtrl.$viewValue.length; i++) {
                                        var selectedId = $scope.getId($ngModelCtrl.$viewValue[i]);
                                        if (id === selectedId) {
                                            return true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    return false;
                                });
                                $scope.unselectedOptions = $scope.resolvedOptions.filter(function (el) {
                                    return $scope.selectedOptions.indexOf(el) < 0;
                                });
                            }
                        };

                        $ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
                            updateSelectionLists();
                        };

                        $ngModelCtrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(function () {
                            updateSelectionLists();
                        });

                        $ngModelCtrl.$isEmpty = function (value) {
                            if (value) {
                                return (value.length === 0);
                            } else {
                                return true;
                            }
                        };

                        var watcher = $scope.$watch('selectedOptions', function () {
                            $ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(angular.copy($scope.selectedOptions));
                        }, true);

                        $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                            $document.off('click', closeHandler);
                            if (watcher) {
                                watcher(); // Clean watcher
                            }
                        });

                        $scope.getButtonText = function () {
                            if ($scope.selectedOptions && $scope.selectedOptions.length === 1) {
                                return $scope.getDisplay($scope.selectedOptions[0]);
                            }
                            if ($scope.selectedOptions && $scope.selectedOptions.length > 1) {
                                var totalSelected;
                                totalSelected = angular.isDefined($scope.selectedOptions) ? $scope.selectedOptions.length : 0;
                                if (totalSelected === 0) {
                                    return $scope.defaultText;
                                } else {
                                    return totalSelected + ' ' + 'selected';
                                }
                            } else {
                                return $scope.defaultText;
                            }
                        };

                        $scope.selectAll = function () {
                            $scope.selectedOptions = $scope.resolvedOptions;
                            $scope.unselectedOptions = [];
                        };

                        $scope.unselectAll = function () {
                            $scope.selectedOptions = [];
                            $scope.unselectedOptions = $scope.resolvedOptions;
                        };

                        $scope.toggleItem = function (item) {
                            if (typeof $scope.selectedOptions === 'undefined') {
                                $scope.selectedOptions = [];
                            }
                            var selectedIndex = $scope.selectedOptions.indexOf(item);
                            var currentlySelected = (selectedIndex !== -1);
                            if (currentlySelected) {
                                $scope.unselectedOptions.push($scope.selectedOptions[selectedIndex]);
                                $scope.selectedOptions.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
                            } else if (!currentlySelected && ($scope.selectionLimit === 0 || $scope.selectedOptions.length < $scope.selectionLimit)) {
                                var unselectedIndex = $scope.unselectedOptions.indexOf(item);
                                $scope.unselectedOptions.splice(unselectedIndex, 1);
                                $scope.selectedOptions.push(item);
                            }
                        };

                        $scope.getId = function (item) {
                            if (angular.isString(item)) {
                                return item;
                            } else if (angular.isObject(item)) {
                                if ($scope.idProp) {
                                    return multiselect.getRecursiveProperty(item, $scope.idProp);
                                } else {
                                    $log.error('Multiselect: when using objects as model, a idProp value is mandatory.');
                                    return '';
                                }
                            } else {
                                return item;
                            }
                        };

                        $scope.getDisplay = function (item) {
                            if (angular.isString(item)) {
                                return item;
                            } else if (angular.isObject(item)) {
                                if ($scope.displayProp) {
                                    return multiselect.getRecursiveProperty(item, $scope.displayProp);
                                } else {
                                    $log.error('Multiselect: when using objects as model, a displayProp value is mandatory.');
                                    return '';
                                }
                            } else {
                                return item;
                            }
                        };

                        $scope.isSelected = function (item) {
                            if (!$scope.selectedOptions) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            var itemId = $scope.getId(item);
                            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedOptions.length; i++) {
                                var selectedElement = $scope.selectedOptions[i];
                                if ($scope.getId(selectedElement) === itemId) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                            return false;
                        };

                        $scope.updateOptions = function () {
                            if (typeof $scope.options === 'function') {
                                $scope.options().then(function (resolvedOptions) {
                                    $scope.resolvedOptions = resolvedOptions;
                                    updateSelectionLists();
                                });
                            }
                        };

                        // This search function is optimized to take into account the search limit.
                        // Using angular limitTo filter is not efficient for big lists, because it still runs the search for
                        // all elements, even if the limit is reached
                        $scope.search = function () {
                            var counter = 0;
                            return function (item) {
                                if (counter > $scope.searchLimit) {
                                    return false;
                                }
                                var displayName = $scope.getDisplay(item);
                                if (displayName) {
                                    var result = displayName.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchFilter.toLowerCase()) > -1;
                                    if (result) {
                                        counter++;
                                    }
                                    return result;
                                }
                            }
                        };

                    }
                };
            });

        }());
```

Comment: Easiest to solve if you create a https://plnkr.co/ for us to review.

Comment: there are many files in the folders! dunno which all to add...but il try with the plunkr

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/jBN92r1iH26LsVv4GDPP?p=preview   here i tried something

Comment: where is you ng-app="" and ng-controller="" in HTML ???
Tuven ng-app and ng-controller use karuna so output tuka {{something}} yetlo

Comment: i did that! its not coming

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/AtxN9Ib3Qf13QTSXSvBB     done! this is the working! all thanks to Avesh Naik! thanks buddy!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your `<Body>` the `ng-app="MyApp"` and to your `<div>` the `ng-controller="MyControllerApp"`.

The result will be

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyControllerApp">
```